# How to express this Node export in the new es6 module syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

How would this kind of (re)export be coded in the new es6 module syntax:

math.js

```
module.exports = {
   PI: 3.14
};
```

module.js

```
const myMath = require('./math.js');

function myFunc() {}

module.exports = {
   PI: myMath.PI, // now is this done in es6?
   myFunc: myFunc
};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to go is using the reexport functionality offered by ES6:

```
# math.js
export const PI = 3.14;

# module.js
export {PI} from './mymath.js';

export function myFunc() { /* TODO */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways of doing it, simplest version

math.js

```
export default {
  PI: 3.14
};
```

module.js

```
import myMath from './math.js';

function myFunc() {}

export default {
  PI: myMath.PI,
  myFunc: myFunc
};
```

A different way of doing it, having multiple exports on your module:

math.js

```
export const PI = 3.14;
export default {
  PI: PI
};
```

module.js

```
import PI from './math.js';

function myFunc() {}

export default {
  PI: PI,
  myFunc: myFunc
};
```

In this case we are only importing PI from our math module

**Note:** You have to use a transpiler for this to work, ES6 modules aren't supported by node yet.

Comment: @materialdreams Remember that Node doesn't support ES6 modules.

https://medium.com/@nodesource/es-modules-and-node-js-hard-choices-2b6995e4d491#.3uncuysee

You will need babel to transpile your backend code.